# Error: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0

I am very new to SharePoint and Development in ASP.net.  And I am stuck on probably something very small. I created a VPC with WSS 3.0, SharePoint 2007, Windows Server 2008. (I followed TechNet's instructions)

## The Issue:

I am creating a web service to pull information from a SharePoint list. I am using the WSS 3.0SDK's code for ReturnListItems and when I run the code I am getting this error.

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

I am not 100% sure where to go from here. I can only assume that the problem is an authentication issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, did you set the webservice credentials to defaultcredentials or are you setting them manually.

```
ws.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

or

```
ws.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userid, password, domain);
```

Second, if you are running everything on the same box, did you configure your backconnectionhostnames correctly?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: I did the following "ws.UseDefaultCredentrials = true;" and I already disabled the LoopBack. Any other ideas?  Thank you

Comment: So everything is on the same box?  If so you wouldn't have the NTLM double hop issue.  Maybe try setting credentials to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yes its on the same box.

Comment: What happened when you set the credentials instead of using the default?

Comment: Maybe run fiddler and examine the results to see what is happening.  Do you have anonymous turned on for the web application?

Comment: the first option works for me like a charm